# How to properly use display: inline with ng repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I want to make a timeline but it has broken structure. I think that is because of `display:inline`, and if I tried to do that to my site:

[image]

it would break it:

[image]

Display inline-block also funks it up.

I tried to `display: inline` to the `overall` div containing the timeline and that didn't work. So then I did it to all the divs that were also in the timeline and that didn't work either.

Timeline:

```
<span class = "timelinefull">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <div class="timeline">              
            <!-- ANCHOR DOT -->
            <div class= "dot">
                <div ng-mouseover="infoIsVisible = true" ng-mouseleave="infoIsVisible = false"   ng-mouseover="getCoords(event)">
                    <img class="icon" ng-src="img/icon_dot.png" height="30px" width="30px">
                </div> 
                <div class="info label label-info" id="info" ng-show="infoIsVisible">
                    <p>Was born</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- REST OF MY DOTS -->

            <div class="dot" ng-repeat="timelineEvent in timelineEvents">
                <timeline-info info="timelineEvent"></timeline-info>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Template for ng-repeat:

```
<div class="timeline-inner" ng-init="infoIsVisible= false">
    <img class="line" src="components/timeline/template-timeline/img/line.png" height="5px" width="{{ info.months }}">
    <div ng-mouseover="infoIsVisible = true" ng-mouseleave="infoIsVisible = false"   ng-mouseover="getCoords(event)">
        <a href="{{ info.link }}">
            <img class="icon" id="icon" ng-src="{{ info.icon }}" height="30px" width="30px">
        </a>
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="info label label-info" id="info" ng-show="infoIsVisible">
    <p>{{ info.description }}</p>
    <p style="font-size: 8px"> Click for more info </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.timelinefull {
    display: inline;
}

.timeline-inner {
    display: inline;
}

.info {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.3s;
    transition:all linear 0.3s;
}

.line {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}

.info.ng-hide {
    opacity:0;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in friends" style="float:left">
   {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
</div>
```

`OR`

```
<span ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
</span>
```

By default `DIV` render as `display:block` and `SPAN` as `display:inline-block`

OR

```
<span class="col-sd-4" ng-repeat="it in elem.tags">
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Made the div with the ng-mouseover a class then displayed it inline-block